# After Upgrading from Xcode 4.2 to Xcode 4.3, instruments command line fails

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

After upgrading from Xcode 4.2 to Xcode 4.3, the `instruments` command line tool fails with the following error:

> Error: No developer directory found at /Developer. Run
>   /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: fastest self answered question ever

Comment: I searched for this first and didn't find an answer, and it was my second time googling for it. Thanks for the upvote. :)