# xcodebuild moved after updating to xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode4.3

Is there a preferred method of updating bashrc to find the location of xcodebuild now?

Since updating to xcode 4.3 my /Developer directory has been removed and terminal can't find xcodebuild anymore. How should I update my system so that I can run xcodebuild from the command line?

Comment: Answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485320/after-upgrading-from-xcode-4-2-to-xcode-4-3-instruments-command-line-fails

Comment: Welcome to SO @Tim Shi, If you have found the answer for your question, you have to answer it your self and then select it as the correct one to set this question's status to "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything related to Xcode is now bundled inside Xcode.app in /Applications.